# Can't ping my public IP from external network

Tags: ip, router

I'm new to networking and I'm trying to scan my external IP from an external network.

I first tried finding my public IP from whatismyIP.com. I assumed that my public IP would be my router's IP, but the IP address from whatismyIP.com was different from the one I saw on my router's web interface inside the network.

I tried scanning the IP I got from whatismyIP.com using **nmap** and also tried pinging it. I was able to do so inside my router's network, but not when I was outside it. I was wondering if anyone could explain why my public IP address was different from my router's external address and why I couldn't ping or scan my address outside my network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why my public IP address was different from my routers external address

Due to the scarcity of IPv4 addresses many ISP use [Carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), where the customers router does not get any public IPv4 address but there is some other router upstream doing the Network Address Translation (NAT), similar how the customer router would to for the customer network. With NAT multiple systems will share the same external IP address, while the internal IP address is not outside.

> why I couldn't ping or scan my address outside my network.

The IPv4 address assigned to the custom router are not publicly routable addresses and thus cannot be directly reached from the internet.

Comment: Thanks. But if the address is not publicly routable and thus cannot be directly reached from the internet, then how am I able to receive messages through that IP. Sorry if my question is dumb.

Comment: @EskimoJones: This is not a security question but a question on how NAT works.  But  is the same mechanism which allows a device in your own internal network (which only have private IP too) communicate with servers on the internet See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation and https://computer.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm to understand how NAT works.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is there any way a hacker could find a way to get my router's public IP despite the use of NAT?

Comment: @EskimoJones: your router has no "public" IP in CG-NAT.